# Unexpected padding under icon font

Tags: css

I've used [Google's material icons](https://material.io/icons/), but there is an unwanted padding below the icons. Why does this appear and how can I correct it ?

```css
.message-text {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="message-text">
  <span class="constellation">
        <i class="material-icons active">star</i>
        <i class="material-icons inactive">star</i>
        <i class="material-icons inactive">star</i>
        <i class="material-icons inactive">star</i>
        <i class="material-icons inactive">star</i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not really a "padding" issue. try  `.material-icons {vertical-align:middle}`

Comment: i can understand the need for vertical alignment, if the container is of a certain fixed height. But here, isn't the container just supposed to wrap around its contents ?

Comment: I lack the technical expertise to explain why it works. All I can say is that it does actually work https://jsfiddle.net/o0vujgqp/

Comment: This is because the class `constellation` is `display: inline`. Try giving it `display: flex;` It should resolve

Comment: `.constellation` is a `span`. Why do you say that it is `display: block` ? And trying a `display:flex` doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: I meant inline, I changed to `div` at my local and told you that value. Anyways both `inline` or `block` will not work